# Jhipster: GridFS upload

Tags: java, mongodb, jhipster, gridfs

I'm new to `JHipster` and wanted to know if it's possible to add/implement `GridFS` upload in `MongoDB` with existing entity generated with `JHipster`,and maybe simple example of it? Thanks.

Comment: Your question lacks many details like which client framework (angular 1 or 4) and what you have tried.

Comment: I used angular 4 and generated basic entity with Jhipster blob type,tried to add gridfs object to repository but i can only add document directly in collection with limit,maybe some sugestion where to look for example?